# how to point to an entire array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

how do we use a new variable, that will be an array itself, and will be assigned all the values from another array ? ( on call )

like for example:

a variable myfood is mine.

there is multiples choices it can become : banana, orange, etc....

```
char banana[3]={"sweet","yellow","fruit"};
char orange[3]={"juicy","orange","fruit"};
```

now , the food i have on me is now a banana. so what i want is:

```
int myfood= banana;
```

but it dont work.....

```
int myfood[]=banana[]; //dont work either

int *myfood

myfood=&banana;

printf(myfood[2]); -------> should equal to 'yellow';
```

all of that dont work.

because im making a big project. I have to pass on parameters depending on the thing u currently use.

so a variable is use, and it will be assigned the correct array depending of which thing you own ( it could be a banana, an apple, etc )..

thanks

Comment: @RyanVincent, re-taged question to `pointers`, instead of `point`, `c` should be the language tag

Comment: Remember that `myfood[2]` accesses the _third_ element, i.e. the last element in your array. (`myfood[0]` would access the first.) Are you still sure you want `myfood[2]` to equal `"yellow"`?

Comment: Already your declaration is invalid: you are assigning three pointers to `char`, so `char*` to three `char`. Compile with all warning levels on.

Answer (score 3):

> how do we use a new variable, that will be an array itself, and will be assigned all the values from another array ?

Don't. Create a *pointer*, which will *point* to the array. Avoid copying!

Say you have these two arrays (whose types I have corrected, to be `const char *`).Then create a *pointer* to char*, and point it at one of the other arrays. Remember, an array degrades to a pointer.

Now use it, remembering that arrays start at index 0.:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char *banana[3] = {"sweet","yellow","fruit"};
const char *orange[3] = {"juicy","orange","fruit"};

const char **food = banana;

int main(void)
{
    printf("%s\n", food[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
yellow
```

Comment: good, but i dotn understand u create an array pointer ? when we use * , it means a pointer.

so you point *banana to these strings , then you point another variable to that pointer...

Answer (score -5):

```
const char* banana[3]={"sweet","yellow","fruit"};
const char* orange[3]={"juicy","orange","fruit"};
const char** food = banana;
cout << food[2] << endl;    // "fruit"
```

Comment: thank but it doesnt work.


what im doing:


int octo[2][3][2]={{{3,4},{3,5},{7,6}},{{2,3},{6,7},{9,18}}}

int hello=octo; 

nothing works. not with **, *, const, & , etc